# Java: scheduling task execution once a month (or two)

Tags: java, scheduled-tasks, quartz-scheduler, scheduler

So I googled about scheduling and it turns out that people mostly need things like "do something once a day", or "every few hours", now I need a task executed every few weeks, shoud I use any other tool than, say Quarz, or will it do just as well as for shorter periods of time, like 8 hours? Taking on account that performance impact matters very much

What I need scheduled is lots of data export from Oracle tables into .csv sheets, sometime at night. The functionality is planned to be implemented using Java.

Comment: Can you add some context? Do you need your app to do something batch every once in a while, do you need something at the OS level? Unix has a lot of nice utilities for that (chron)

Comment: @DiegoMartinoia I updated the description, hope its more clear now.

Comment: You still haven't clarified your question. Are you asking what Java libraries will allow you to do this? What do you mean by performance impact? Do you mean the overhead of triggering the task by time, or the impact of the actual ETL? Are you worried about whether you can still use Quarz even on shorter intervals?

Comment: @DiegoMartinoia Yes, I am asking about Java libraries for such stuff About performance - I expect that there would be some kind of timer that will wait for the moment to launch my task, and that timer (or whatever the mechanism) shouldn't noticeably impact the overall performance (I only worry about it because the timer is supposed to wait a lot). I do know that Quarz is ok to use on shorter intervals, and I at this poing consider the most suitable for me, but now I am also considering using [this approach](https://blogs.oracle.com/jamesbayer/entry/a_simple_job_scheduler_example)

Comment: I don't think Quarz will fail miserably on longer intervals, though I'm not expert. I still reccommend you to look into OS level scheduling though: chron jobs or the like can take a lot off your app, given that it seems that these tasks are complementary to it and nto core.